# How to turn this kind of json code into a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, json, rvest, jsonlite

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

page_2 <- "[{ position: [-5.25, -80],                        type: 'icoMC',                        codEsta: '105135',                        monEsta: 'BUENOS AIRES',                        htmlPag: 'Estaci&oacute;n: <b>BUENOS AIRES </b><br /> <a href=\"javascript:popUp(\\'Ver Datos\\')\" onClick=\"popUp(\\'_dat_esta_tipo.php?estaciones=105135\\',\\'670\\',\\'650\\',\\'1\\',\\'50\\',\\'50\\'); return false;\">Ver Datos</a>'                    },{ position: [-12.861333333333, -76.054833333333],                        type: 'icoHF',                        codEsta: '213101',                        monEsta: 'PACARAN',                        htmlPag: 'Estaci&oacute;n: <b>PACARAN </b><br /> <a href=\"javascript:popUp(\\'Ver Datos\\')\" onClick=\"popUp(\\'_dat_esta_tipo.php?estaciones=213101\\',\\'670\\',\\'650\\',\\'1\\',\\'50\\',\\'50\\'); return false;\">Ver Datos</a>'                    },{ position: [-15.217944444444, -72.935638888889],                        type: 'icoHP',                        codEsta: '115151',                        monEsta: 'CUYAU',                        htmlPag: 'Estaci&oacute;n: <b>CUYAU </b><br /> <a href=\"javascript:popUp(\\'Ver Datos\\')\" onClick=\"popUp(\\'_dat_esta_tipo.php?estaciones=115151\\',\\'670\\',\\'650\\',\\'1\\',\\'50\\',\\'50\\'); return false;\">Ver Datos</a>'                    },{ position: [-10.420722222222, -77.714972222222],                        type: 'icoHP',                        codEsta: '110141',                        monEsta: 'MALVADOS RINCONADA',                        htmlPag: 'Estaci&oacute;n: <b>MALVADOS RINCONADA </b><br /> <a href=\"javascript:popUp(\\'Ver Datos\\')\" onClick=\"popUp(\\'_dat_esta_tipo.php?estaciones=110141\\',\\'670\\',\\'650\\',\\'1\\',\\'50\\',\\'50\\'); return false;\">Ver Datos</a>'                    },{ position: [-5.7716805555556, -79.397688888889],                        type: 'icoHF',                        codEsta: '105136',                        monEsta: 'SAUZAL',                        htmlPag: 'Estaci&oacute;n: <b>SAUZAL </b><br /> <a href=\"javascript:popUp(\\'Ver Datos\\')\" onClick=\"popUp(\\'_dat_esta_tipo.php?estaciones=105136\\',\\'670\\',\\'650\\',\\'1\\',\\'50\\',\\'50\\'); return false;\">Ver Datos</a>'                    },{ position: [-3.6927888888889, -73.256247222222],                        type: 'icoHF',                        codEsta: '240304',                        monEsta: 'SANTO TOMAS PUNCHANA',                        htmlPag: 'Estaci&oacute;n: <b>SANTO TOMAS PUNCHANA </b><br /> <a href=\"javascript:popUp(\\'Ver Datos\\')\" onClick=\"popUp(\\'_dat_esta_tipo.php?estaciones=240304\\',\\'670\\',\\'650\\',\\'1\\',\\'50\\',\\'50\\'); return false;\">Ver Datos</a>'                    },{ position: [-6.3735333333333, -79.466730555556],                        type: 'icoHF',                        codEsta: '106138',                        monEsta: 'PUCHACA',                        htmlPag: 'Estaci&oacute;n: <b>PUCHACA </b><br /> <a href=\"javascript:popUp(\\'Ver Datos\\')\" onClick=\"popUp(\\'_dat_esta_tipo.php?estaciones=106138\\',\\'670\\',\\'650\\',\\'1\\',\\'50\\',\\'50\\'); return false;\">Ver Datos</a>'                    }        ]"
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I tried this, but it didn't work

```
page_2 %>%
  jsonlite::fromJSON()

#error:

Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
{ position: [-5.25, -80], 
(right here) ------^
```

Comment: You could use V8 as per [this](https://github.com/jeroen/jsonlite/issues/197) but I'm not sure I want to promote this method as I have no idea how safe it is. Basically, you want a method that safely handles unquoted keys and doesn't simply evaluate potentially malicious strings.

Comment: This is because for a valid `json` you should have all characters enclosed in quotes, ie `"position"` and not `position`

Comment: The string is so irregular, go back to the source and get a correctly formated string, or use `rvest` to get data from the source